# Flutter: Alternative to Downloads path provider 28

Tags: flutter, plugins

I have a feature in app where user and download some content he generated. The data comes from assets and dart file string. I want it to get downloaded to Android's downloads directory. The plugin downloads_path_provider_28 uses a deprecated api or embedding. I wanted to know about any plugin that can replace it and work well. I already tried flutter_file_downloader, file_saver, external_path. But none works for my case.
https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider_28 works fine but it might not work in future flutter versions thus i want a newer plugin support.

This is the change I made in my code.

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;

// import 'package:downloads_path_provider_28/downloads_path_provider_28.dart';

class KMLGenerator {
  static generateKML(data, filename) async {
    try {
      // final downloadsDirectory = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
      // Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
      var path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/";
      var savePath = io.Directory(path);
      // var savePath = downloadsDirectory?.path;
      final file = io.File("$savePath/$filename.kml");
      await file.writeAsString(data);
      return Future.value(file);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return Future.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

The error I get:

```
I/flutter ( 9449): FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/'/SO2_Emission.kml' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

The error is the extra '/

One more thing to mention, it works with downloads_path_provider_28 so I am not sure whats the plugin doing differently

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
class KMLGenerator {
  static generateKML(data, filename) async {
    try {
      Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
      var savePath = dir.path;
      final file = File("$savePath/$filename.kml");
      await file.writeAsString(data);
      return Future.value(file);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return Future.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Seems initialising with datatype Directory did the charm. I will still appreciate if anyone can tell how the extra `'/` comes in the approach I was doing earlier.

Comment: What version of Android do you use? Did it work on Android >= 11?

Answer (score 1):

I always use this method to get download directory on android

```
var path = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/";
var downloadDir = io.Directory(path);
```

it might help you

Comment: it doesn't work for me... I am updating my question to show you what changes I made.. the device it doesn't work with is a Lenovo M10 FHD Plus TB 606V tablet.. I am using VScode editor, flutter 3.3.4